# Konqueror opens with multiple "save as" dialogs open

Tags: debian, kde, konqueror

When I launch konqueror (either from console or shortcut, simply using `konqueror` command), it opens, but then immediately opens two "save as" dialogs (both targeting the downloads dir with a filename of "blank"). If I try to actually click save rather than cancel, another popup appears saying `Unable to create io-slave, Unknown protocol 'konq'.` I have no idea (a) what's making the save dialogs appear or (b) what they're trying to save (though I suspect the former Q is the only one that matters).

My Konqueror is Version 22.12.0, I'm using KDE Plasma 5.26.4 on a distro of Debian specific to my employer.

Comment: Happening here too. I'll post solution if I find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just now I had the same issue.
I fixed it like this step by step.

1. Open this file:

   ~/.config/filetypesrc
2. Remove or comment out the following line:

   embed-text/html=false
3. If you previously selected "to perform this action on all files of this type", you also need to remove or comment out the next line too:

   askSavetext/html=true

Comment: Thanks, that did work (after a reboot). How did you figure it out? And a (maybe) related problem, after a reboot my system always launches 6 or 7 separate Konqueror windows (no save as dialogs). This behavior happened before and after your fix. Any ideas how to fix that one? It's less of a big deal, since I only reboot once a month or so, but I launch Konqueror quite often... so you've solved the major issue, thanks again!

Comment: This issue is related to file type association. I knew this because I had encountered to another problem with file type association earlier. But I didn't remember the location of the configuration file whith these settings. So I created new user and launched Konqueror without this issue, then started downloading some file and in the confirmation dialog checked "save". Then I found the modified user config files by time. When I found the file path I needed, I edited it for the main user. Since the Konqueror start page is html, I assumed that this issue was related to the html type.

Comment: @The111 about your second issue, I think you have started Konqueror too many times and it keeps open windows. You can try three ways:

1. Open:
Konqueror -> Settings -> KDE Performance 
And uncheck both checkboxes, then push apply button and reboot the system.

2. Kill all Konqueror processes via the terminal or task manager and restart the system.

3. Be careful, next method is radical!
You can try deleting all Konqueror config files, but before you need to kill all Konqueror processes. Konqueror folder path:
~/.local/share/konqueror/

If this helps, please let me know. :)

Comment: Thanks, the first suggestion (simple preference change) worked! Wish I could accept your answer twice. :-) Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome.)